# how to connect database using mysqli keyword

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new in PHP  and follow [this tutorial](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html) connect php webservices to android below is my code  i change `MySQL` to `MySQLi`  everywhere  but still its show error:

[image]

```
    <?php
$host="localhost"; //replace with database hostname 
$username="root"; //replace with database username 
$password=""; //replace with database password 
$db_name="emp_info"; //replace with database name

$con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot  
  connect"); 
mysqli_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "select * from emp_info"; 
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
$json = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$json['emp_info'][]=$row;
}
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($json); 
 ?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_select_db` that takes 2 parameters. Please read the manual. Now, using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  would have told you about it.

Comment: There is literally no point to write `"$username"` in your code when `$username` will do. It would be in your best interest to shed these awful habits.

Comment: i just simple copy paste the tutorial code     http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html

Comment: the tutorial's pretty crappy. you'll find that probably 95%+ of php tutorials on the web are outdated, badly written, full of security vulnerabilities, or just plain wrong. there's a LOT of crap out there.

Comment: Oh, and this `$result = mysqli_query($sql);` is also failing you. RTFM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php as a wise man once said ;-)

Comment: Couldn't agree with you more there Marc - @MarcB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solution, first use the 4th argument in `mysqli_connect()`.

Like this:

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name)
```

Second, you need pass the connection in `mysqli_select_db()`

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($con, $db_name);
```

Almost all function in MySQLi needed the conection at first argument, so `mysqli_query()` need the connection too.

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name)or die("cannot connect"); 

$sql = "select * from emp_info"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); //<--- here query need the connection
```

Comment: You missed something there Ray.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what i missed?

Comment: Look at the OP's code again very carefully. Comments up there should give you a clue ;-)

Comment: rray i did what u say but its still show error

Comment: ( ! ) Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\samplejson.php on line 8

Comment: @Fred-ii- thx for the notice, i think is fixed now.

Comment: @syedahmed i think you are print something wrong not an array.

Comment: its work  thnx you rray